# ClassCast Exception can't cast String to Boolean

Tags: java, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Boolean value from Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642716/how-to-get-boolean-value-from-object)

I am trying to get the `Boolean` value of `Object` `newValue` and get `ClassCastException` here.
Although, I type cast it to `Boolean` why do I get this `exception`?

```
Boolean changedValue=!((Boolean)newValue);
```

Can you please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you would be able to cast a String to a boolean?

Answer (score 8):

A `String` and a `Boolean` are totally different classes, so you can't cast between them.  You need to use `Boolean.valueOf()` to get a `Boolean` from the `String.`.

It's not like C or C++ where you can forcibly cast anything to anything (though of course you can get into a lot of trouble doing so if you're not careful, since there's no guarantee an arbitrary cast will have any meaning).

And it's also not like C++ where if there are are type conversion operators defined, the cast will turn into an automatic call to one of the conversion operators.  There are no automated conversions between object types in Java.

Comment: But newValue is of type Object.

Comment: @RandonP: any object can be down-cast to `Object` - but you can't up-cast `Object` to anything.

Answer (score 3):

Java is a strongly typed language.  If `newValue` is not a `Boolean` object then you will get a `ClassCastException` if you try to cast it to a `Boolean`.  If `newValue` is a `String` representing a `Boolean` value you can try the following code:

```
boolean changedValue = Boolean.parseBoolean( newValue )
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: there is no String.parseBoolean method.

Comment: Yea, sorry.  Meant Boolean.parseBoolean( newValue ).  Thanks Greg for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If that is a string value, you'll want to use `Boolean.valueOf(String)` method. Java does not convert objects into different types automatically only converts via autoboxing between wrappers and primitive types.