# How to get Boolean value from Object

Tags: java, classcastexception

I tried different ways to fix this, but I am not able to fix it. I am trying to get the Boolean value of an **Object** passed inside this method of a checkBox:

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) 
{
    final String key = preference.getKey();
    referenceKey=key;
    Boolean changedValue=!(((Boolean)newValue).booleanValue()); //ClassCastException occurs here
}
```

I get:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Comment: First you are assuming newValue is of type Boolean. You can use instanceof to check the type of newValue. If it is a boolean, with autounboxing, you have no problem. If it's a string, you can compare (ignoring case) for values "true", "false", then create the appropriate boolean representation.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of casting it, you can do something like

```
 Boolean.parseBoolean(string);
```

Comment: you could also check for instanceof Boolean and instanceof String if you needed to handle each case... but doesnt look like that here

Comment: This only takes strings not objects

Comment: And he is pretty much only working with strings it would seem, therefore my solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some of the source code for the Boolean class in java.

```
// Boolean Constructor for String types.
public Boolean(String s) {
    this(toBoolean(s));
}
// parser.
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s);
}
// ...
// Here's the source for toBoolean.
// ...
private static boolean toBoolean(String name) { 
    return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

So as you can see, you need to pass a string with the value of "true" in order for the boolean value to be true. Otherwise it's false.

```
assert new Boolean( "ok" ) == false; 
assert new Boolean( "True" ) == true;
assert new Boolean( "false" ) == false;

assert Boolean.parseBoolean( "ok" ) == false; 
assert Boolean.parseBoolean( "True" ) == true;
assert Boolean.parseBoolean( "false" ) == false;
```

Answer (score 3):

From the code you posted, and the result you are seeing, it doesn't look like newValue is a boolean. So you try to cast to a Boolean, but it's not one, so the error occurs.

It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Ideally you'd make newValue a boolean.  If you can't do that, this should work:

```
boolean newValue;
if (newValue instanceof Boolean) { 
    changedValue = newValue; // autoboxing handles this for you
} else if (newValue instanceof String) {
    changedValue = Boolean.parseBoolean(newValue);
} else { 
    // handle other object types here, in a similar fashion to above
}
```

Note that this solution isn't really ideal, and is somewhat fragile.  In some instances that is OK, but it is probably better to re-evaluate the inputs to your method to make them a little cleaner.  If you can't, then the code above will work.  It's really something only you can decide in the context of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your `Preference` is a `CheckBoxPreference`, then you can call [isChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#isChecked%28%29).  It returns a `boolean`, not a `Boolean`, but that's probably close enough.

Here is some code from the [APIDemos Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html) sample (DeviceAdminSample.java).

```
private CheckBoxPreference mDisableCameraCheckbox;

public void onResume() {
    ...
    mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, mDisableCameraCheckbox.isChecked());
    ...
}

public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
...
    boolean value = (Boolean) newValue;
...
    else if (preference == mDisableCameraCheckbox) {
        mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, value);
        reloadSummaries();
    }
    return true;
}
```